# getting a decimal and returning it in tuple form. F#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I have a function that returns a decimal say: 5.839895013,
how do I get it to return that decimal in tuple form such as (5,8).
I tried doing mod but I get this

> 5.839895013 % 10.0;;
>   val it : float = 5.839895013

Comment: This question is too ambiguous to give a single answer. What does the first tuple element contain? One digit? The number as an integer? The sign? Those are double-precision floats, not decimals, unless you mean decimal digits, which can't be tuples on their own. You can very well use `%` in this context, use for example `% 1.` to obtain the decimal places including the sign. E.g. if the sign should stay everywhere, a solution function might be `let asTuple f = int f, f * 10. % 10. |> int`.

Answer (score 4):

First of using `mod` with floating point numbers does not work out (as you've seen) - and even if it would do the conversation to integers it would give you the remainder (which is an integer) of dividing your number by 10 - so I would expect it to be 5 or 6 (depending on if you expect rounding or not)

---

A better approach IMO is to cut of the part after the `.` and use some basic math with this:

Assuming you want an tuple of two `int` it can be as easy as:

### using some type conversation trickery:

```
let tupled x = 
   let first = int x 
   let second = int ((x - float first)*10.0)
   (first, second)
```

yielding

```
> tupled 5.839895013;;
val it : int * int = (5, 8)
```

### using `System.Math`

moving the `*10` and maybe more readable:

```
let tupled x = 
   let first = int (System.Math.Floor x)
   let second = int (System.Math.Round x*10.0) - 10*first
   (first, second)
```

---

also note that the second version uses different roundings:

```
> tupled 5.86;;
val it : int * int = (5, 8)
```

vs.

```
> tupled 5.86;;
val it : int * int = (5, 9)
```

Comment: I am new to F# but experienced in Java so I've been knocking my head trying to do it the Java way. It worked awesomely thank you!